# Which of the following ideals $J◃\mathbb{Z}$ contain strictly $I$:

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of the polynomials with integer coefficients, it is given the principle ideal $I = ⟨x^2+2x⟩ ◃ \ \mathbb{Z}[x] $, generated by $x^2+2x$.

Which of the following ideals $J◃\mathbb{Z}$ contain strictly $I$:
$$
J=⟨x^2−4⟩◃Z[x]
$$
$$
J=⟨x^2⟩◃Z[x]
$$
$$
J=⟨x⟩◃Z[x]
$$
$$
 J=⟨x−2⟩◃Z[x]
$$
$$
J=⟨x^2−2x⟩◃Z[x]
$$
$$
J=⟨x+2⟩◃Z[x]
$$
My attempt: Since $x^2 + 2x = x(x+2)$ I was thinking that the answers are: $J=⟨x⟩◃Z[x]$ and $J=⟨x + 2⟩◃Z[x]$. But it's not the right answer. Any tips ?

Comment: What does $x2$ mean?

Comment: @AnikBhowmick it's $x^2$, my bad

Comment: Your solution seems to be correct unless I'm missing something trivial. From where did you get this question and the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Any principal ideal that contains the principal ideal $I$ has generator which divides the generator of $I$ (this happens basically because by Gauss Lemma $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is U.F.D.). As you observed, $x^2+x=x(x+2)$ hence any other ideal $J=\langle q(x)\rangle$ such that $I\subseteq J$ must satisfy $q(x)\mid x(x+2)$. Now we notice there are not many polynomials dividing $x(x+2)$ and so either $J=\langle x\rangle$ or $J=\langle x+2\rangle$. As any of the choices of $J$ gives a maximal ideal and $I$ is not maximal, we have strict inclusions.